# Rename XML child using XSLT - XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

does anyone know how I can rename a tag using XSLT?

In my example I copy the tag "NUMBER" from "CONTACT/NUMBER" at the Tag "ADD" to "GRP".
But now I also want the copied Tag "NUMBER" at "GRP" to be called "CONTACT_NUMBER" instead of "NUMBER".

```html
<xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:copy>
<!--copy the data from ADD - CN to the GRP so it can be used in the mapping to set the delivery address from end customer-->
        <xsl:for-each select ="./ADD">
         <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='CN'">
          <xsl:copy-of select="PARTY_NAME_1"/>    
          <xsl:copy-of select="STREET_1"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="CITY"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="POSTAL_CODE"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="COUNTRY_CODE"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="CONTACT/NUMBER"/>
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    <!--copy all other nodes-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Result:

PARTY_NAME_1

STREET_1

...
CONTACT_NUMBER (instead of "NUMBER")

Thanks, Julian

Comment: Why are you copying the input elements, AND applying templates to them? I would normally expect to see one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:copy-of select="CONTACT/NUMBER"/>
```

to

```
<CONTACT_NUMBER>
  <xsl:value-of select="CONTACT/NUMBER"/>
</CONTACT_NUMBER>
```

That should do the job.